# Monitoring Application Metrics Using JMX & VisualVM

Tags: java, hadoop, jmx, visualvm, java-opts

I am trying to monitor some Java Application specific Metrics. Appliation is running on Hadoop(yarn) and I'm using Linus Ubuntu to run some local jobs. I have HADOOP_OPTS set up in hadoop-env.sh for namenode datanode & resourceManager and I can see all related Metrics in localhost:8004/jmx and VisualVm for hadoop...however I can't see any of application Metrics which should ran on Application Master. 
when i try $JAVA_OPTS (which is in /.bashrc) i get:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8005 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

but when i run application and use $ ps -ef | grep SoTJob i only get:

```
vdhf  27200 5497  0  11:27   pts/10   00:00:00  grep  --color=auto SoTJob
```

so it's not seeing the config apparently. Am i setting it in a wrong place? am i missing something? 
do i need more setting?
I saw in some other related questions that some people pointed to a plugin to enable JMX. can anyone explain it to me please?
thanks for all the helps.

Comment: The app is running within (typically more than one) ResourceManager JVM, not as its own Java process on only one machine

Comment: so by that you mean I have to have the configs on hadoop-env.sh and then metrics should show up on ResourceManager Mbeans? If that's what you mean, I tried it and didn't get any result

Comment: My point is that I don't think you have access to a single running application under YARN. Definitely not through the YARN / Hadoop JMX properties